# VB6: API spying

Tags: api, vb6, spy

I'm trying to control some soulseek features from VB6 - the problem is the SysTabControl32 - how can I read out which tab is selected? The API spy only returns the SysTabcontrol32 but no tab button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest try the [TCM_GETCURSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760583(v=VS.85).aspx) message. It should return the index of the currently selected tab.

The code is something like this below - I adapted this from vbAccelerator's [cTabCtrl](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/utilities/ActiveX_Documenter/ActiveX_Documenter_Source_zip_cTabCtrl_ctl.asp) but haven't tested it.

```
Private Const TCM_FIRST = &H1300 
Private Const TCM_GETCURSEL = (TCM_FIRST + 11)
Private Declare Function SendMessageLong Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
 (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As _
 Long) As Long

Public Function SelectedTab(ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    SelectedTab = SendMessageLong(hWnd, TCM_GETCURSEL, 0, 0) + 1
End Property
```

Comment: @wqw Thanks, slight copy/paste failure there! As I say I haven't tested it. Fuxi, did you try the code out?